# How can I retrieve a generated value from my C#-code into my web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know, that the following code looks naive, but it should only bring to mind, what I want to achieve.

My `web.config` file:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="AppData.GetConnectionString()" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I want to get the string from C#:

```
public class AppData
{
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return "LDAP://expample.domain.com:389/DC=example,DC=domain,DC=com";
    }
}
```

I know it is possible to get data from the `web.config` in the C# code (The AppSettings for example). But is the opposite also possible?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with the `connectionStrings` section. You could, if you really wanted, make your own section and have it evaluate an expression in an attribute using roslyn or something.. but that seems really weird. I would just not use configuration files at all in your case.

Comment: You are using config file in very wrong way.

Comment: The purpose of putting the connection string in the configuration file is so it can be changed without recompiling the application. This seems to totally defeat the purpose. And if you are going to ignore best practices and hard code it, why bother with the config file at all?

Comment: I would recommend putting your connection string into a DB if you have a lot of those instead of keeping it a string in your codebase.

Comment: @Aleksandr Ivanov: I want to use Forms authentication that authenticates against the AD. I only found examples in the internet, where I have to define the LDAP connection string in the web.config. Is it possible to define the connectionstring inside my c# code directly?

Comment: This seems like an "old shoe or glass bottle" question to me.

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c2kcht0(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I DO NOT recommend use it. But you actually can do something like this:

```
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Configuration;

var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["ADConnectionString"].ConnectionString = AppData.GetConnectionString();
config.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible as it is just an **XML file**. All you can do in XML file is add comment,create nodes,add attributes or add nested elements  etc etc **but you cant add any code to it**.

However I think there are certain languages that allow you to do so

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486772/write-php-code-inside-xml-file

Answer (score 0):

Use `Reflection`

Here's an example:

```
private string test = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString; //returns "ExecuteTest" -- note! no parenthesis!

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MethodInfo m = this.GetType().GetMethod(test); //expects static method
    if (m != null)
    {
        object result = m.Invoke(this, new object[] { });
    }
}

private static void ExecuteTest()
{
    //do stuff
}
```

But no, you can't edit/pull data into the web.config on the fly. Changing the web.config will cause the application to restart killing all sessions.  It's possible to build the web.config prior to starting but once it's up and running it's essentially locked down.